# как мне добавить параметр disable=false в созданную кнопку маркера

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5, yandex-maps-api

я хочу создать кнопку, которая будет показывается в зависимости от пользователя, который открыл ее. Шаблон для балунов я пишу в html, поэтому я не могу указать параметр  `disable=false`. Он его просто не будет видеть. `document.getElementById("buttun2").disabled = false;` тоже не помогает. Прошу любой подсказки. Спасибо.

```
markers.forEach(marker => {
    var balloonContentBody = '<div class="cd-quick-view">' +
        '<div class="cd-slider-wrapper">' +
        '<ul class="cd-slider">' +
        '</ul> ' +
        '<ul class="cd-slider-navigation">' +
        '</ul> ' +
        '</div> ' +
        '<div class="cd-item-info">' +
        '<h2>Marker Title</h2>' +
        // '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia, omnis illo iste ratione. Numquam eveniet quo, ullam itaque expedita impedit. Eveniet, asperiores amet iste repellendus similique reiciendis, maxime laborum praesentium.</p>' +
        `<p>Автор метки: ${marker.author}</p>` +
        '<ul class="cd-item-action">' +
        '<li>'+
                '<button id="buttun1" class="add-to-cart1" disabled= false>Add to cart</button>'+
                '<button id="buttun2" class="add-to-cart2">Add to cart</button>'+
                '<button id="buttun3" class="add-to-cart3">Add to cart</button>'+
        '</li>' +
        '</ul>' +
        '</div>'  +
        '</div>'
var placemark = new ymaps.Placemark(marker.coord.split(','), {
    balloonHeader: 'Заголовок балуна',
    balloonContent:balloonContentBody,
    balloonFooter: 'Футер балуна'
},{
    balloonShadow: true,
    // balloonLayout: balloonContentBody,
    // Запретим замену обычного балуна на балун-панель.
    // Если не указывать эту опцию, на картах маленького размера откроется балун-панель.
    balloonPanelMaxMapArea: 1,
    hideIconOnBalloonOpen: false
});
// Добавим метку на карту.
mapRef.current.geoObjects.add(placemark);
    document.getElementById("buttun2").disabled = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

для установки атрибута к элементу нужно применить метод setAttribute

document.getElementById("buttun2").setAttribute('disabled','true')

removeAttribute для удаления атрибута соответственно

Comment: Спасибо, но это тоже не работает Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setAttribute'), я так понимаю это связано так как я добавляю это динамически и он не может найти этот класс